# How StringBuffer Objects are Compared for equality

Tags: java, stringbuffer

```
 String s="";
StringBuffer sb2=new StringBuffer("hi"); 
StringBuffer sb3=new StringBuffer(sb2);
    StringBuffer sb4=sb3;

    if(sb2.equals(sb3))
    {
        System.out.println("sb2.equals(sb3):"+sb2.equals(sb3));
        s+="2 ";
    }


    if(sb3.equals(sb4))
    {
        System.out.println("sb3.equals(sb4):"+sb3.equals(sb4));
        s+="3 ";
    }
```

Why first if is giving false and second giving true given that s2,s3,s4 all are StringBuffer objects and String Buffer do not have equal() method?

Comment: Where is sb2 defined? Please give us a [mcve]

Comment: You have not showed us how sb2 was created. Most likely its a separate object. But you have explicitly coded that sb4 = sb3, so that is why the 2nd part is true.

Comment: @Jens Does it really matter? `sb3` is still a new object, doesn't matter how `sb2` was created.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes. to verify it you must have it

Comment: @Jens `StringBuffer sb3=new StringBuffer(sb2); sb2.equals(sb3)` will always be false, no matter how sb2 was created.

Answer (score 6):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) the Javadoc for `StringBuffer` class, it lists `equals` as one of the methods inherited from class `java.lang.Object`.

So, it does not override the `equals` method which means `Object` class's `equals` method is used to compare two `StringBuffer` Objects. As it just checks the references (i.e. with `==` operator), you are getting `false` for `sb2.equals(sb3)` (they are two different `Objects`).

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) the Javadoc for Object's `equals` method, it says the following:

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one. The equals
>   method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object
>   references

Comment: Aww you beat me to it :)

Comment: You're too fast xD

Comment: @Ankit It is not an "important point", it is the answer for what you're asking...

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuffer` does not override `equals()`, so it inherits `Object`'s `equals()` implementation, which essentially is the same as `==`. This means that:

- `sb2.equals(sb3)` is false because sb2 and sb3 reference different objects.
- `sb3.equals(sb4)` is true because both reference the same object.

Answer (score 1):

all other class is actually a subclass of `Object` class so `StringBuffer` is a subclass of `Object` in your declaration

if you look at the `Object` class documentation it contains the `.equals()` method this method returns true if both the object have the same hash code

if you look at the `StringBuffer` class documentation it doesn't have the `.equals()` method because it actually inherits the `.equals()` method of the superclass `Object`

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuffer` does not override the `equals` method. All classes are subclasses of `Object.java` and hence objects of `StringBuffer` inherits the `equals` method. The implementation in `equals` in `Object.java` considers reference equality based on the result of `==` , it simply returns as `return (this == obj);` where `obj` is parameter to the `equals` method (`public boolean equals(Object obj)`)

`String.java` does override the `equals` method. You should use that by obtaining the `String` Object from the `StringBuffer`

For equality you may use as below.

```
StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("abc");
StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("abc");
if( (sb1.toString()).equals(sb2.toString())){
    System.out.println(" true ");
}else { 
   System.out.println(" false ");
}
```